# Disable UglifyJSPlugin when doing development work?

Tags: typescript, webpack, uglifyjs

My relatively simple typescript React webapp takes a fair amount of time compiling when I make changes, a large chunk of this is spent with the UglifyJSPlugin.

I'm running the following command via NPM:

> "start": "webpack-dev-server --progress --colors --inline --watch",

Most of the time spent is in uglifyjs, is there any reason it needs to run for dev work? I don't need it to be uglifying/optimizing code during development and was wondering how I could force it to be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a separate webpack config file for production, leaving the UglifyJSPlugin out in your development config.

You could also make your config script generate a config object that only includes that plugin if you're running in production (eg. process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production').

I have opted for the latter, personally. I recently upgraded to WebPack 4.x, which adds the optimization field to config, allowing that to be succinctly expressed like so:

```
{...restOfConfig,
   optimization: {
      minimize: process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production'
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your dev environment, enable the **development** mode by adding the following line into `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    // ...,
    mode: 'development',
    // ...
}
```

Note the [official document](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/#usage) show that the `UglifyJSPlugin` is only activated in **production** mode.